# High revs in 5th gear

Tags: transmission

Recently replaced the clutch in my 2006 Ml triton but it is reving very high When driving in 5th gear. Other gears are fine no over reving

Comment: Can you give example revs in 5th gear before and after the clutch change.

Comment: Sounds like the clutch may be slipping - DO NOT keep driving in these conditions when they occur. Instead, check why the clutch slips and repair it. Perhaps the pressure plate is worn out.

Comment: I should have mentioned it was already reving in fifth before I got the clutch done (sorry I’m new to this car trouble thing ) could it be a bearing  ? Or mabe gear box is on way out ? Thank u

Comment: Handyhowie I change from fourth to fifth around  3,000 no noise or over revving until it’s in fifth gear . I can do 100ks take my foot of excellorator the noise lessons but not by much